# Regex: order matters?

Tags: regex

I was trying to strip all non-numeric characters from a phone number.

So, suppose we have numbers in this format: "(123) 456-7890".

```
Regex.Replace(phone, @"[ -()]", string.Empty)
```

leaves the dash in. Same with () escaped ("\(\)").

This

```
Regex.Replace(phone, @"[() -]", string.Empty)
```

works, though.

I thought that order of characters in [] doesn't play a role ? In fact, I get same results if I switch space and dash around.. But brackets have to go first to work ?

Comment: You could avoid the problem entirely using the non-numeric character class - \D `Regex.Replace(locationProperties.Phone, @"\D", string.Empty)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-` can be used to declare a range, e.g., `[a-z]`. You need to escape it: `[ \-()]`.

The exception is if you put the dash at an end of the character group, where its only meaning can be a literal `-`.

Comment: Duh.. I suspected I forgot something :) I'll accept it as an answer as soon as SO will let me.

Answer (score 3):

`-` is a special character in this context, denoting a range (e.g. `[a-zA-Z0-9]`).  When it appears at the end, it cannot denote a range and so works correctly.

The correct solution is to escape it with a backslash: `\-`.

Answer (score 3):

The placement of the hyphen matters because hyphens are used inside character classes (`[]`) to signify a range, such as `a-z`. So with the hyphen at the end, the regex engine knows you are not intending the dash to be used in a range, because there's nothing after it. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html